# PHP mySQLi insert query not inserted last value

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this query:

```
    $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO userdata(Username, Name, Department, Access, Password) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
    $query->bind_param('sssdi', $accname, $name, $department, $access, $accpass);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
```

The variables are:

```
    $accname = 'js1234';
    $name = 'Joe Smith';
    $department = 'New';
    $access = '0';
    $accpass = md5('joe1234');
```

The mySQL structure is:

```
    Column     Type         Null    Default
    ID     int(11)      No       
    Username   varchar(6)   Yes     NULL     
    Name       varchar(50)  Yes     NULL     
    Department varchar(15)  Yes     NULL     
    Access     int(11)  Yes     NULL     
    Password   varchar(32)  No
```

But when I run the php code it only inserts the number 63 into the Password column of the database and not the full md5 hash.  Everything else inserts fine. What am I missing in the php query?

Comment: a md5 hashed password is as close to plain text as you can get

Comment: `MD` stands for "Medical Doctor", and in this case OP, one just may be needed once the OP's DB gets hit. @Dagon ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are trying to insert a string as an integer, you will need to insert your password hash as a string

```
$query->bind_param('sssds', $accname, $name, $department, $access, $accpass);
                      //^ note the "s" here for string instead of "i" that you used
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked.  I tried googleing to see if what the different 'sssdi' there was but couldn't find anything.